# how to insert this type of video onto wordpress site

Tags: html, wordpress, plugins

How does one insert a video in a manner done in websites such as http://www.leadpages.net? where the video plays the moment the site is loaded and auto replays without any play buttons/full screen options/etc. It behaves in a way similar to that of gifs

My site uses wordpress/divi theme

Answer (score 0):

WordPress comes with a cool feature called auto-embed. It can automatically get the embed code for video from video sites like YouTube and many more.

All you need to do is paste the video URL into the post editor. Make sure that the URL is in it’s own line and not clickable (hyperlinked), and that you are using the visual editor :)

Comment: when you say "Make sure that the URL is in it’s own line and not clickable (hyperlinked)" is this the step that makes the video autoplay with no normal video buttons to press? aka what seperates this type of video from just a standard video?....i know about the auto embed option, but this is used to create a standard video, im looking for the specific 1 mentioned in the example